# Java Payment Installments Calculator

Tags: java

Need to create java class to generate section 2 from section 1.
How to create that.?
Please help..

```
-------------------------------section 1---------------     
Total Amount        15000
First Intalment     5000
Installments        5
-------------------------------section 2---------------     
Installment 1       2000
Installment 2       2000
Installment 3       2000
Installment 4       2000
Installment 5       2000

Total           10000
-------------------------------------------------------
```

just plain java class i need. in main method i'll enter manually those section 1 data's
then i need to out put get to ArrayList or possible Collection object

Comment: How are sections 1 and 2 delivered, as a flat text file (or otherwise) or as assigned values internal to a class?

Comment: @JoshDM : Post Changed

Comment: what is the input to the program? What format, file, user entry etc

Comment: @Priyan at Dialog, you need to provide more infomation. It looks like you have 3 columns. You can create a class with 3 attributes to hold each. A String, an int and a long. But without the additional information the names won't make sense. After you have that class, you can then make store the info in a collection of instances and output the info.

Comment: @PriyanatDialog - your post may have changed, but you didn't answer my question.

Comment: System.out.println("Installment 1       2000\nInstallment 2       2000\nInstallment 3       2000\nInstallment 4       2000\nInstallment 5       2000"\n"; // :)

Comment: @All : Question edited again..need only method how to iterate data's and get those as a output/ArrayList or any Collection Object..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple mathematics: You have a `numberOfInstallments`, the `totalAmount` and an `initialInstallment`.

- First get the left over amount with `totalAmount - initialInstallment`.
- Next divide by `numberOfInstallments`.

In Java is becomes something like this:

```
int totalAmount = 15000;
int initialInstallment = 5000;
int numberOfInstallments = 5;

// Calculate the height of each installment
int installment = (totalAmount - initialInstallment) / numberOfInstallments;

// Print to screen
for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfInstallments) {
    System.out.println("Installment " + i + "  " + installment);
}
System.out.println("Total " + (totalAmount - initialInstallment));
```

(I did not bother to properly align the output, but that should not be too hard.)